# UIButton font size issue inside UIView animation

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiviewanimation, ios-autolayout

I have a strange issue with `UIButton`s inside a UIView. The view is initially constrained to a height of 0, and I'm animating the constraint using

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

        heightConstraint!.constant = height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }) { (finished) in

    }
```

This works really well, with all the content of the animated view appearing as expected, apart from any UIButtons that are placed inside.

**The buttons' `titleLabel` font size increases from 0 to the correct size during the animation**. There's nothing special about these buttons; they are set to system font of 18, positioned relative to the superview. The button frames are correct, its just the font size that changes.

I've tried explicitly setting `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` and `contentMode` but these have no effect. Interestingly, if I add a plain `UILabel` to the view, this works just fine.

Any suggestions as to what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I'm managed to avoid the issue by explicitly setting the height to a non-zero value before the animation:

```
constraint.constant = 1
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
self.view.setNeedsUpdateContraints()

// do animation
```

This resolves the issue, although it feels like a hack around something I'm not doing correctly in the first place.

Comment: It's ok if you just call self.view.layoutIfNeeded() before the animation and constraint setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `clipsToBounds = true`, Text is hiding inside the button

When height is 0 or 1, myView is

[image]

and after setting `clipsToBounds = true`, its like this

[image]

**Note** Border = 1 and height = 1 is just to represent here. Even I'm getting this strange issue. But the text do not display after setting the bounds to true

Comment: No effect I'm afraid!

Comment: Check if this [helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184104/uibutton-inside-a-uiview-not-working-after-uiview-is-animated?rq=1)